# How do I specify random factors in R?

Tags: r, nlme, random-effects

How do I specify random factors in R ?

If I have a factor `x1`  which is supposed to be random , can I try something like this ?

```
lm(y ~ x1, data = p)
```

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to achieve ?  Do you want to create some random factors, or do you want to do a linear regression against two factors of a data frame ?, some example data + code would really help...

Comment: So if I try  lme4(y ~ x1, data = p), will x1 be treated as a random factor ?

Comment: I suspect x1 will be treated as "Error: could not find function "lme4"" since there is no function named lme4.

Answer (score 5):

Most simply (using the older `nlme` rather than the new `lme4`),

```
library(nlme)
lme(fixed = y ~ 1, random = ~1|x1, data = p)
```

The equivalent in `lme4` is:

```
library(lme4)
lmer(y~1+(1|x1), data = p)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you by chance looking for the [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lme4) package which is focussed on linear mixed-effects (ie. fixed versus random) modelling?

Comment: if I write  lm(y ~ x1, data = p), 
x1 will be treated as a fixed factor in R , 
Im wondering if there is way in R to specify that x1 is a random factor

Comment: Yes, in the **lme4** package. Follow the link in my answer and read up on the documentation of the lme4 package. The `lm()` function is for basic linear modelling and does **not** support random effects.

Answer (score 2):

Zuur et al 2011, Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R, has an excellent walk through of random effects using the nlme package.  They explain the differences between fixed, random, and mixed models and how to specify random intercepts and random slopes.